# How to show one's own forked-repo Issues in VS Code?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, github-issues

I forked [tidythemes/blankslate](https://github.com/tidythemes/blankslate) to [robertandrews/blankstrap](https://github.com/robertandrews/blankstrap).

I created new Issues for myself, for my own fork...

[image]

But, in VS Code, in the GitHub extension panel, I am instead seeing the Issues for the original blankslate...

[image]

I would like to be seeing my own Issues in VS Code.

Source Control Repositories shows...

[image]

Branch switcher shows...

[image]

Switching to another (ie. origin/master Remote) does not result in my Issues showing.

**What must I do to get** ***my*** **own Issues visible?**

Comment: The only way I can get them to display so far is by editing settings.json to add a new githubIssues.queries item:

```
    {
      "label": "Test Issues",
      "query": "state:open repo:robertandrews/blankstrap sort:updated-desc"
    }
```

Then, they show. But this, of course, means this is visible no matter what I open in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Developer of the VS Code GitHub Issues extension [suggests](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-pull-request-github/issues/3573#issuecomment-1141954022) it may be a bug.